# Single predictor soft thresholding

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, convex-optimization, regularization

I have found in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1498712169) the following problem
$$\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{minimize}}\left\{\frac{1}{2N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N(y_i-z_i\beta)^2+\lambda|\beta|\right\}$$
for parameter $\beta>0$ known real sequences $y_i$s, $z_i$s and known $N\in\mathbb{N}$. The non-differentiability at zero and the fact that this cannot be decomposed into $N$ minimizations since $\beta$ is common for all measurements are my problems here. So (by inspection) they propose the following optimal solution for $\beta$:
$$
\hat{\beta}=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{N}\langle\mathbf{z},\mathbf{y}\rangle-\lambda,&\quad\frac{1}{N}\langle{\mathbf{z}},\mathbf{y}\rangle>\lambda\\
0,&\quad\left|\frac{1}{N}\langle{\mathbf{z}},\mathbf{y}\rangle\right|\leq\lambda\\
\frac{1}{N}\langle\mathbf{z},\mathbf{y}\rangle+\lambda,&\quad\frac{1}{N}\langle{\mathbf{z}},\mathbf{y}\rangle<-\lambda
\end{array}
\right.
$$
But the proof of this is not clear to me. Can you give any hints?

Comment: I suppose $\beta>0$ should actually be $\lambda>0$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to minimizing the function
$$
 f(x)
 =\frac12(x-y)^2+\lambda|x|
$$
as a function of $x\in\mathbb R$, where $y\in\mathbb R$ and $\lambda>0$. It seems that this can be done by inspection, but I would suggest to use the concept of [subdifferentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) and look for the subdifferential that contains $0$ as its element.

Denote the subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ by $\partial f(x)$. Then
$$
 \partial f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 \{x-y-\lambda\}&\text{if}\ x<0;\\
 [-y-\lambda,-y+\lambda]&\text{if}\ x=0;\\
 \{x-y+\lambda\}&\text{if}\ x>0.
 \end{cases}
$$
Hence,
$$
 x^\star=
 \begin{cases}
 y+\lambda&\text{if}\ y<-\lambda;\\
 0&\text{if}\ |y|\le\lambda;\\
 y-\lambda&\text{if}\ y>\lambda.
 \end{cases}
$$
Equivalently,
$$
x^\star
 =\mathcal S_\lambda(y)
 =\operatorname{sign}(y)(|y|-\lambda)_+,
$$
where $\mathcal S_\lambda:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is the soft-thresholding operator with $\lambda\ge0$.

We have that
\begin{align*}
 &\frac1{2N}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i-z_i\beta)^2+\lambda|\beta|=\\
 &=\frac1{2N}\sum_{i=1}^N(y_i^2-2y_iz_i\beta+z_i^2\beta^2)+\lambda|\beta|\\
 &=\frac12\Bigl[N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i^2-2N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^Ny_iz_i\beta+N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^Nz_i^2\beta^2\Bigr]+\lambda|\beta|\\
 &=\frac12[N^{-1}\|y\|_2^2-N^{-2}(y^{\operatorname T}z)^2]+\frac12[\beta^2-2\beta N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z+N^{-2}(y^{\operatorname T}z)^2]+\lambda|\beta|\\
 &=\frac12[N^{-1}\|y\|_2^2-N^{-2}(y^{\operatorname T}z)^2]+\frac12(\beta-N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z)^2+\lambda|\beta|,
\end{align*}
where we used the assumption that $N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^Nz_i^2=1$. It follows that
$$
\hat\beta=\mathcal S_\lambda(N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z)
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
 \hat\beta=
 \begin{cases}
 N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z+\lambda&\text{if}\ N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z<-\lambda;\\
 0&\text{if}\ |N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z|\le\lambda;\\
 N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z-\lambda&\text{if}\ N^{-1}y^{\operatorname T}z>\lambda.
 \end{cases}
$$

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The exercise in question (2.2 of SLS) actually instructs you *not* to make use of subgradients, so here is such a proof. Let $\hat{\beta}_o=\mathbf{z}^\intercal\mathbf{y}/N$ be the usual OLS estimator, and define $\ell(x)$ to be the loss function in the minimization problem. We have

$$
\ell(b)-\ell(a)=\frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{2}+\hat{\beta}_{o}(a-b)+\lambda(|b|-|a|).
$$
If $|\hat{\beta}_{o}|<\lambda$ then
$$
\ell(b)-\ell(0)\ge\frac{b^{2}}{2}-\hat{\beta}_{o}b+|\hat{\beta}_{o}b|\ge0,
$$
so the minimum is achieved when $b=0$.

Otherwise, suppose $\hat{\beta}_{o}>\lambda$, so that

$$\ell(b)-\ell(\hat{\beta}_{o}-\lambda)\ge\frac{1}{2}\left(2\lambda|b|+b^{2}-2\hat{\beta}_{o}b+(\hat{\beta}_{o}-\lambda)^{2}\right).
$$

If $b<0$ then this is obviously non-negative, while if
$b>0$ then
$$
\ell(b)-\ell(\hat{\beta}_{o}-\lambda)\ge \frac{1}{2}(b-\hat{\beta}_{o}+\lambda)^{2}.
$$
Thus the loss function is minimized when $b=\hat\beta_o-\lambda$. The case $\hat\beta_o<-\lambda$ follows from applying the above result to the predictor $-\mathbf{z}.$